# how to refresh page in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to make tab in my app using **ng-show**.I am able to implement that .But I have one rendering issue .it is not display on screen but it is present in dom .It will display on page only when you inspect your screen or code .

In other words I have three tabs (**FY-16,key des, HC)**by default first is selected .When you switch to second tab (key des) .it display the contend (background color change).But when user move to swtich third tab **(HC & SCW)** it is not showing data .It will show data when you do **inspect element** .Then it show data in table .
http://plnkr.co/edit/4SkebhzjBIc1qRAo4cX7?p=preview

```
$scope.handlerButtonClick = function (section) {

            showLoader();

            $scope.activeContentArea = section;
            if ($scope.activeContentArea == "FY16_18_design") {
                $ionicLoading.hide()
               // showViewFyDesign()
            } else if ($scope.activeContentArea == "key_design_health") {
                $ionicLoading.hide()
               // showViewkeyDesignHealth()
            } else {
                $ionicLoading.hide()
            }

        }
```

Steps to produce bug

- Run plunker "Move to third tab(HC &SCW)"
- Notice that data is not display on table .if you inspect element(right mouse click and select inspect element) than it show data in table

how to why it is not display data ? how to refresh screen?

Comment: slider class has default css `visibility:hidden` when inspecting. As soon as toggle that property rule can see data.

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: visibility:hidden to visible it works thanks